# Non-type template function overloading problem

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, function-templates-overloading

Consider:

```
template <size_t >
class SizeFlag {};

template <size_t START, size_t END>
void asd(SizeFlag<START>, SizeFlag<END>) {
}

template <size_t START>
void asd(SizeFlag <START>, SizeFlag<START + 1>) {
}

template <class T>
class TypeFlag{};

template <class T,class F>
void qwe(TypeFlag<T>,TypeFlag<F>){}

template <class T>
void qwe(TypeFlag<T>,TypeFlag<T*>){}

int main()
{
    asd(SizeFlag<1>{}, SizeFlag<2>{});// call to 'asd' is ambiguous in clang-11
    qwe(TypeFlag<int>{}, TypeFlag<int*>{});// use void qwe(TypeFlag<T>,TypeFlag<T*>) 
    cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is `qwe(TypeFlag<T>,TypeFlag<T*>)` more specialized than `qwe(TypeFlag<T>,TypeFlag<F>)`, but `void asd(SizeFlag <START>, SizeFlag<START + 1>)` is not more specialized than `void asd(SizeFlag<START>, SizeFlag<END>)`?

Comment: Non-type parameters is problematic as I remember, Doing some test with class specialization has issue with similar comparison [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vv659j9sT) even if the class way work in that case... :/

Comment: Overloading and templates is a hairy combination. The "partial ordering process" part of [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) is relevant, but gives me too much of a headache to want to figure it out.

Answer (score -2):

"more specialized" applies to your class templates, not the functions as you wrote them.  The functions are overloaded, and not "related" in the same way that the partial specialization of classes is.

You did not write something like

```
template <size_t START>
void asd<>(something something) {
}
```

That is, there's no `<>` in your second function.  It is **simply overloaded**, not a specialization of the *same* template.

The rules to determining if a function argument is a *better match* are things like `T` vs `T&`, and don't consider that the second function has fewer template arguments than the first.

The complete rules can be seen at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading

Comment: Function template specializations can be more specialized: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over#match.best.general-2.5

Comment: @NathanOliver I clarified

Comment: My question is why call to qwe is success and call to asd is fail because of ambiguous .

if it is second function has fewer template arguments don't make it better match,why  `void qwe(TypeFlag<T>,TypeFlag<T*>)` is a better match but `void asd(SizeFlag <START>, SizeFlag<START + 1>)` don't.
PS. it is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading use "more specialized" in "Function template overloading" to describe better match.

Comment: @uncertaintyprinciple because that's what the rules state!  `T*` is a more specialized template match.  Arbitrarily picking a template with fewer template arguments is not anything special.  Go through the rules listed at that reference page and see why the example works; go through the non-working example and reach the end without it determining a preference.